# how can i simplify this array to make MySQL where condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [ram] => 2 GB )
    [1] => Array ( [ram] => 4 GB )
    [2] => Array ( [ram] => 6 GB )
    [3] => Array ( [screen_size] => 5 - 6 Inch )
    [4] => Array ( [screen_size] => 6 - 7 Inch )
    [5] => Array ( [network_connectivity] => 3G )
    [6] => Array ( [network_connectivity] => 4G )
)
```

How can simplify that array to use in mysql `where` clause???
for example=

select * from table where (ram = '2GB' or ram = '4GB') and (screen_size = '5 - 6 Inch' or screen_size = '6 - 7 Inch') and (network_connectivity = '3G' or network_connectivity = '4G')

I have tried

```
$condition = "";
if(!empty($this->input->post('datafilter'))){
foreach ($this->input->post('datafilter') as $mainfilter) {
  foreach ($mainfilter as $key => $value) {
   //echo $condition.'<br>';
   if(!empty($condition)){
    if (strpos($condition, $key) === true) {
       $con = ' AND ';
    } else {
      $con = ' OR ';
    }
    }
    else{
      $con = ' OR ';
    }
    $condition .= $key.' = '.$value . $con;
  }
}
}
```

and result is:
ram = 2 GB OR ram = 4 GB OR ram = 6 GB OR screen_size = 5 - 6 Inch OR screen_size = 6 - 7 Inch OR network_connectivity = 3G OR network_connectivity = 4G OR

Comment: Hey dude, add your mysql query too!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very well in PHP (i am Perl programmer), but this code seems to work as you expected:

```
<?php
    $optList=[
        [ 'ram' => '2 GB' ],
        [ 'ram' => '4 GB' ],
        [ 'ram' => '6 GB' ],
        [ 'screen_size' => '5 - 6 Inch' ],
        [ 'screen_size' => '6 - 7 Inch' ],
        [ 'network_connectivity' => '3G' ],
        [ 'network_connectivity' => '4G' ]
    ];
    $optByItems=[];
    foreach ($optList as $opts) {
        foreach ($opts as $item => $value) {
            $optByItems[$item][$value]=1;
        }
    }
    $query='';
    foreach ($optByItems as $item => $values) {
        $query .= (empty($query) ? '' : ' AND ') . "($item='" . join("' OR $item='", array_keys($values)) . "')";
    }
    echo $query;
?>
```